# JQuery username validation - Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, jquery-validate

I am currently using JQuery's validation plugin for basic form validation such as required fields.

I want to add functionality so that when the user types in the username field, an ajax call is triggered to check whether the username is already taken. My requirements are:

- Preferably integrate with JQuery Validation plugin, rather than writing a custom function
- I want the lookup to occur on the keyup event
- I want the lookup to be triggered approx 0.5 seconds after the keyup event has occurred.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found this post:
http://www.twu.ca/divisions/technology/sst/orion/blog/jquery-autocomplete-and-asp-net-validation.html

It may point you in the right direction